# How can I load a PNG image from a resource to a TImage at runtime?

Tags: delphi, resources, png, delphi-2009

How can I load a PNG image from a resource to a TImage at runtime ?

The `TImage.Picture` has no `LoadFromResourceName` method. But it can load a PNG at design time !

I tried `[TImage].Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'BALANCE_OFF');`... but it says "Resurce BALANCE_OFF not found.". But it's there !

.rc file looks like this:

```
BKG_TEXTURE  BITMAP  "BKG_TEXTURE.BMP"
BKG_FOTO     RCDATA  "BKG_FOTO.PNG"
BALANCE_ON   RCDATA  "BALANCE_ON.PNG"
BALANCE_OFF  RCDATA  "BALANCE_OFF.PNG"
```

Comment: That won't work because it's not a bitmap. Create a TPngImage, the use its LoadFromResourceName method then assign it to the Picture.